# Get result from more than one colum MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the results from two MySQL columns with PHP, but I can only retrieve one.

Below is my code.

```
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id, Email, User_Password, twitter FROM user_detail WHERE Email = :Email );


    $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();

    $user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $twitter = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: You want to fetch the whole row (fetchAssociation) in a single variable.  This will return an array with all columsn you requested, indexed by column name.

Comment: try `$user_id = $stmt->fetchColumn(); //for 1st column $email = $stmt->fetchColumn(1); //for 2nd column.` and closing quotes is missing at  `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("");`

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) I guess ?

```
$stmt->execute();
if($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $user_id = $row['name'];
   $twitter = $row['twitter'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$stmt->execute();
$datas = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($datas as $d) {
    echo $d['user_id']. '<br>';
    echo $d['Email']. '<br>';

    print_r($d); 
}
```

It will help you to understand how this work I think, print_r will show you the array of the current item, each element is accessible by $d[key];

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to close a double-quote on the prepare() line.
2. use fetchAll() instead of fetchColumn()

**fetchColumn()** - Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.

**[fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)** - Returns an array containing all of the result set rows.

Since you already specified which columns to select in your SELECT statement, performing fetchAll() is perfect for what you're trying to achieve.